# Is it possible to ignore order with patch?

Tags: bash, patch

I was wondering if it is possible to apply a patch file where the order of the lines might differ.  So for example:

file.txt:

```
PARAM5
PARAM4
PARAM3
PARAM2
PARAM1
```

file.patch:

```
--- f1.txt      2014-03-31 11:15:38.543560653 -0400
+++ f2.txt      2014-03-31 11:25:11.029173000 -0400
@@ -2 +1,0 @@
-PARAM2
@@ -4 +2,0 @@
-PARAM4
```

Here, I would want to remove `PARAM2`, `PARAM4` from file.txt, but they may not be in that order in the file I'm removing them from.  (note: I could write a script to do this, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this before I proceeded).

Comment: No, there's no _elegant_ way.  `patch` doesn't provide anything that'd do this _out-of-the-box_.

Comment: I don't think you will find anything to do that. After all what is the correct behavior if `PARAM2` is met multiple times?

Comment: `patch` is not a general purpose editor; it applies a fixed change to a *known* file state, so it is implicitly assumed that not only are the relative order of `PARAM2` and `PARAM4` known, but their exact locations in the target file are known as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I was just checking.

Comment: Have you tried using `sed` for this? On your example file, `sed -i '/^PARAM[24]$/d' file.txt` would do what you want.

Comment: If I were actually looking only for PARAM2, PARAM4, that would be good, but in reality, I'm comparing two files, and creating a 'patch' which should be applied to other files (which might be ordered differently).  As it turns out, it's not that hard to script.